# Displaying Multiple Results in FME with a Spatial Intersection

Tags: spatial-join, fme-form

I have a workspace that outputs planning scheme data against properties. Quite a few properties have multiple overlays and some have multiple planning zones. However, I am finding no matter which transformer I use (clipper, spatial filter etc) I am not getting all overlays against some properties. I tried validating geometry but it is still not giving the correct results. Sometimes only one overlay will appear depending on the settings, but when I manage to get multiple overlays appearing there always seems to be some missing. Is there something obvious I'm missing?

[image: Here are the general settings I use for the clipper and the spatial filter]

Comment: I tested again with AreaOnArea Overlay and filtered on one of the planning overlays that wasn't appearing and it appears against the test property. Once I remove the filter other planning overlays appear but not this one. Could this be a bug or is there a limit of overlapping features FME will show?